# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<int>" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>"

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется задача, получить последовательность строковых представлений только нечетных значений integerList и отсортировать в порядке возрастания. Для этого нужно использовать Linq в одну строку в return.

Вот моё решение:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> Task5(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
{
return integerList.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).OrderBy(x => x);
}
```

Которое выдает вот такую ошибку:

> (параметр) IEnumerable integerList
> Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов). [Linq]

Объясните пожалуйста как решать и что означают подобные ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда неявно не получается, можно попробовать явно.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Task5(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
{
    return integerList
        .Where(x => x % 2 != 0)
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => x.ToString()); // или по-модному x => $"{x}"
}
```